# CompactPCI system running Debian linux: lspci shows incorrect IRQ leading to gen_irq flags mismatch and IRQ conflict

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am working with a 3U compactPCI system with an Advantec MIC3325 processor [manufacturer site](http://www.advantech.com/products/3u_compactpci/mic-3325/mod_b2d10efe-b665-4c38-a776-b6bcd08228ad) and several plugin cards one of which is an 8 port serial card [datasheet](https://www.mksinst.com/docs/UR/tentaSCOM-080Xds.pdf). This serial card exposes 2 Oxford OX16PCI954, which each emulate 4 16C950.

I am building a kernel from linux 4.9.4 source, but the problem I describe is the same in a stock Debian 8 install (kernel 3.16)

By manually configuring the linux tty serial 8250 driver I am able to get all 8 ports to work, but I need to workaround 2 problems to do so.

**The first problem** is detecting the IRQ. In the past I have used *lspci* and parsed the output. however I am finding that this IRQ is not always correct. eg:

```
05:0c.0 Serial controller: Tenta Technology Device 0800 (prog-if 06 [16950])
 Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 18
 Region 0: I/O ports at ec00 [size=32]
05:0c.1 Bridge: Tenta Technology Device a801
 Interrupt: pin B routed to IRQ 10
 Region 0: I/O ports at e800 [size=32]
```

I have tried turning off the APIC, by kernel option and directly in the BIOS and I have tried all combinations of ACPI configuration, while the IRQ is changed in some cases it is still not reliably correct, and generally I run in to worse problems in both cases. I am *not* using device tree, and while MSIX is turned on this device does not support MSI so this seems irrelevant. The board does work with polled interrupts but I lose data on the serial line so this is not a solution.

I have read many discussions about how interrupt routing works and how the link from PCI pin number to IRQ number occurs, but I cannot find any documentation on how to change or debug the configuration. eg perhaps there is an extra swizzle since the first chip acts as a PCI bridge to the second chip, but I don't know enough to dig deeper.

The same (incorrect IRQ) is found using the pci_dev structure in code and by navigating the virtual filesystem */proc/bus/pci*. This problem occurs with other cPCI plugin cards in other slots and in different chassis (backplanes).

At this point you may wonder how I know the IRQ is incorrect. Well I have 2 cases, one when there is another device using the correct IRQ and a second when there is not. The second case is the simplest, the port simply does not work.

In the first case **when data is received at the port** eventually in *dmesg* I will see:

```
[57.301692] irq 19: nobody cared
...
[57.302684] Disabling IRQ #19
```

Using *cat /proc/interrupts* I see that IRQ 19 is registered to some USB port

```
19:      24987      25004      25000      25009   IO-APIC  19-fasteoi   uhci_hcd:usb2
```

I use my *setserial /dev/ttyS6 port exe800 irq **19** autoconfig* to force the serial port to use IRQ 19 instead of IRQ 10 shown in lspci.

This leads to the **second problem** which is:

```
[40.875178] genirq: Flags mismatch irq 19. 00000000 (serial) vs. 00000080 (uhci_hcd:usb2)
```

I managed to disable USB ports in the BIOS and get the serial port to work correctly on IRQ 19. I know it is working because the number of IRQ19 interrupts increases in /proc/interrupts when data is being sent (and received) in the port.

I checked the code in 8250_core.c and cross reference my kernel compile flags and it appears that the driver is set to shared interrupts:

```
CONFIG_SERIAL_8250_SHARE_IRQ=y
```

As a last resort I hacked 8250_core.c to force always to used shared interrupts:

```
ret = request_irq(up->port.irq, serial8250_interrupt,
                              IRQF_SHARED, "serial", i);
```

This has actually worked around the genirq flags mismatch problem. But I dont understand why the existing code does not set the UPD_SHARE_IRQ bit in the 
uart_port.port.flags when manually configuring the port using *setserial*.

So to summarise my questions, can anyone help with:

1) Why does lspci show the incorrect IRQ? (in my case 10 instead of 19)?

2) Why does the 8250_core kernel driver not set the UPD_SHARE_IRQ flag when manually configuring the port, and is there a way to do this without hacking the driver code?

Comment: *vanilla* -- is from Linus' tree, *stock* -- is from distro.

Comment: According to what you described above you should have only **two** instances of *driver*, but **eight** instances of 8250 *port*. So, basically your devices as far as I understood should share 2 lines per each 4 ports.

Comment: @0andriy Sorry about the terminology, I mean stock. What do you mean by instances of? I may be missing something fundamental about how modules work.

Comment: The ideal solution would be to modify the 8250_pci driver to support each of the two PCI devices.

Comment: Although the block diagram on the [datasheet](https://www.mksinst.com/docs/UR/tentaSCOM-080Xds.pdf) shows 2 OX16PCI954 devices, I think that is incorrect. The OX16PCI954 is a dual -function PCI device. Function 0 has the quad UARTs, and function 1 can be configured in various ways, but in this case as a bridge to an 8-bit local bus with an I/O region mapped onto the additional UARTs. Each of the two functions appears as separate PCI device in Linux, as can be seen in the _lspci_ output.

Comment: @Ian Thank you for the advice. I have learned how to do this and implemented the VENDOR ID and two DEVICE's IDs in 8250_pci. This has worked well, and seems to have solved the problem of UDP_SHARE_IRQ flag not being set.

Comment: @JamesDale Did you use one of the existing `pbn_b0_4_*` configuration values, or did you have to create a new entry in `pci_boards[]`? The [datasheet](https://www.mksinst.com/docs/UR/tentaSCOM-080Xds.pdf) suggests a maximum baud rate of 1.25 Mbps, which doesn't match any of the existing entries in `pci_boards[]`. Do you know the frequency of the crystal oscillator on the card? The `.base_baud` value should be that frequency (in Hz) divided by 16.

Comment: @Ian I created a new pbn_b0_4_ since I have been using setserial I know that .base_board=1250000 works so I set it to that. Thanks for the tip, I was stumped for a sec how to set that up